# Commercial game crashes at launch with: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Filen eller assemblyen 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: .net, windows-11

My GOG copy of Spacechem started to crash at startup the other day on my Windows 11 machine (fully updated).  Reparing and reinstalling didn't help. After poking around a bit I found that the zicrash file listed

```
Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Filen eller assemblyen 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' eller en af dens afhængigheder kunne ikke indlæses. Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
Filnavn: 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
   ved #=q$8$$I4Mf1JKnj3g$y4uj4Q==.#=qFWLRlWJfKM1XFnOxiHt81g==()
   ved #=q$Ms6qF3PBgUNpBt146_KhkgwHdbILL7qmYawLOhB6Bw=.#=qXWdxPFaWEbTGnRcnAngCAA==(#=q$8$$I4Mf1JKnj3g$y4uj4Q== #=q9Id63pJjjZGZOhn1pfeoNQ==)
```

which appears to be a very old version of System.Runtime.Serialization which apparently for some reason is needed but not present anymore (as it used to work).

Is this a faulty build or is there a simple way to reinstall this dependency?

I have Visual Studio Community 2022 installed (but used very little) if it helps with installing nuget packages.

Comment: What version of .NET does your application target? What .NET runtimes are installed on the system?

Comment: @AyoubKaanich this is not my application but a game I have downloaded from GOG. What commands should I execute to get the information you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is missing .NET 3.5 (assuming the software in question is as old as I think)

Try installing it with "Turn Windows features on or off"

[image: Turn Windows features on or off]

See also https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows

Comment: Removing .NET framework 3.5 caused Windows 11 to prompt installing it from Windows update when trying to launch the game, and then the game didn't crash.  Thank you.